# Watch star rating in page and rate in the other

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am new to Django and I'm using Star-Rating.
I would like to know if there is a possibility a user can see the ratings on one page without the opting to rate and on another page, the same user can rate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wanted to show a user's rating user Django star-rating,
where In one page a user can see all the other user's ratings without being able to change them
and on another page, a user can see a user's rating and is able to change their ratings
you can see below how i solved it

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

if you want a star-rating object to be 'read only'
you can set read-only in the object tag to a value of True
like this:

```
{% ratings <object name> read_only = True%}
```

if you want to enable rating you can just leave out the tag